# gdb - "Attempt to extract a component of a value that is not a structure pointer"

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm debugging C++ using Kinetis Design Studio on an Cortex-M4.

There's a tab `Expressions` where you can enter a custom expression to view the value of the variable.

In my environment, the location in RAM of an allocated object never changes no matter how many times I reset, reload, run.

So, I know it should be possible to do this:

`((ClassA *) 0x12345678)->ClassA_member`

but for some reason it's not working.

The `gdb` trace when I try to input this expression is:

```
513,896 244-stack-info-depth --thread 1 50
513,905 244^done,depth="11"
513,905 (gdb) 
513,905 245-var-create --thread 1 --frame 0 - * "((CXCPHostProtocolProperties * )0x1fffc2c4)->_MaxDT\
O"
513,907 246-data-evaluate-expression --thread 1 --frame 0 "&(((CXCPHostProtocolProperties * )0x1fffc\
2c4)->_MaxDTO)"
513,907 245^error,msg="Type CXCPHostProtocolProperties *(CXCPHostProtocolProperties * const) is not \
a structure or union type."
513,907 (gdb) 
513,908 247-data-evaluate-expression --thread 1 --frame 0 "((CXCPHostProtocolProperties * )0x1fffc2c\
4)->_MaxDTO"
513,908 246^error,msg="Attempt to extract a component of a value that is not a structure pointer."
513,908 (gdb) 
513,910 247^error,msg="Attempt to extract a component of a value that is not a structure pointer."
513,910 (gdb)
```

What am I doing incorrectly?
The `ClassA_member` is a **public** `unsigned short`

Also I'm using `-Os` to optimize for size (in case that matters).

Comment: Try `-O0` to get reliable debugging results..

Comment: @JesperJuhl I realized it's something else: the GUI doesn't parse my expression correctly. It interprets `(ClassA *) 0x12345678` as having the type `ClassA*(*)(ClassA*const)`; that's word for word. So then it passes that to `gdb` and voila we have a problem.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but ((ClassA *) 0x12345678)->ClassA_member is correct. It works in gdb.